# how to store the combobox value in dataverse column

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, dataverse

I am learning powerapps using the canvas module.

what I am facing an issue:

I am not able to store the data in the column I need help

I google it and found the link for a solution but I am not able to solve the problem

see that link :

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/patching-people-picker-to-SharePoint/td-p/560085

[Image of column in dataverse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVKYG.png)

see my caller column in canvas app

[caller column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Od1w.png)

see flows how I add the column:

form1->field->edit fields->add filed->caller field I add in form

then after I take another combo box and set the

```
items = Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:ComboBoxCaller.SearchText,top:10})
```

and inside Combobox, I am able to see the users in Combobox but now I want to store the user in caller column in dataverse

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your caller column in dataverse is set to a yes/no column type. You will need to delete it and create a new one making it a person field.

After that, refresh your data source in the left hand side menu.

Next, add the caller column to your form again, then you should be able to just assign the value by using your linked example or even assign the default of default selected as:

```
TheOtherColumn.Selected
```